# PL/SQL procedure random timestamp

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

how i can generate a random timestamp and put it into a var?

Thanks,

Tommaso

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this solution

start_date + dbms_random.value(0,86400*(end_date-start_time)+1)/86400

at

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/122604/2/

Answer (score 0):

not real sure why but something along the lines of the following pseudocode:

find a random number in a sufficiently large range, and either add or subtract that to SYSDATE.

Answer (score -1):

we have random number generater in oracle...and this random number can be used to add in sysdate to get random dates..or time stamp.